# The probabilistic method with a network graph

Tags: network, probabilistic-method

This is a question from a course about probabilistic methods in combinatorics.

Let a network be represented by a graph G (each user is represented by a vertex and every communication route between two users is a set of edges connecting their two vertices).

There are n disjoint couples of users who wish to communicate. 
Every couple $P_i$ has a list $F_i$ of $m$ possible routes in which they can communicate. Routes are said to be *cut* if they contain a mutual edge.

Assume that for every *i,j* and for every route in $F_i$ there are at most $k$ routes in $F_j$ that cut $F_i$, and $8nk \leq m$.

Prove that every couple of users $P_i$ (every two vertices) can be connected by routes from their lists $F_i$ s.t. no two routes are cut.

Idea: Choose a route for each couple of vertices. Got stuck with figuring out how the events are dependent in order to use Lovász local lemma.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to obtain a dependency graph for the local lemma is as follows: if

1. your random object is obtained by choosing a bunch of independent random variables, and
2. each event is determined by a subset of those random variables,

then each event is independent of all those events that use a disjoint subset of random variables. (In other words, two events are adjacent in the dependency graph if they share a random variable.) In special cases, you might be able to have fewer dependencies, but you will never need more.

Here, we have:

- Random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ with each $X_i$ uniformly sampled from $F_i$: it's a uniformly random route connecting couple $P_i$.
- An event $A_{ij}$ for every pair $i,j$: this is the event that route $X_i$ cuts route $X_j$.

The event $A_{ij}$ is determined by the random variables $\{X_i, X_j\}$, and therefore the dependency graph should be as follows: $A_{ij}$ depends on $A_{i1}, A_{i2}, \dots, A_{in}$ (all events that care about $X_i$) and on $A_{1j}, A_{2j}, \dots, A_{nj}$ (all events that care about $X_j$).

That's $2n-2$ events, not counting $A_{ij}$ itself, which plugs directly into the symmetric local lemma to give you a condition slightly weaker than $8nk \le m$.